# Django: URLField for image: URL from remote or local static file

Tags: django

I have the following field in my `Article` model:

```
picture_url = models.URLField(null=True)
```

`article_as_dict` is a dictionary obtained from an external source. If it contains an image URL, I want to save that as my URL. However, If there is no URL from external path, I want to reference a local `.jpg` **as a URL** (so I can save it to the field). How can this be achieved?

Comment: I think Heroku will remove static files after a certain period, (1 day, I think)

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.templatetags.static import static

if article_as_dict['picture_url']:
    url = article_as_dict['picture_url']
else:
    url = static('path/to/local/static_file.jpg')
```

If i understood correct, it works, try it

Comment: I’ve already tried something like this. This works in development but when I try to collectstatic for Heroku deployment it complains about a missing manifest for the image file.

Comment: Yes. The website is already live and all other components are working great it’s just this missing manifest for the picture that the deployment script is complaining about.